# JSON Parsing Array of objects with identifiers

Tags: .net, json

The Json I need to parse (using json.net) is an array of objects in what the service is calling "by identifier":

JSON representation of an array of Messages by identifier.
messages    array   An array of Message objects keyed by a string identifier.

For example:

```
{  
   "messages":{  
      "349149733:-4:0:0":{  
         "name":"Fred",
         "text":"Body for test message.",
         "subject":"Test Message 1",
         "referenceId":"349149733"
      }
      "253413023:-4:0:0":{  
         "name":"Fred",
         "text":"Body for the next test message.",
         "subject":"Test Message 2",
         "referenceId":"253413023"
      }
      ....
   }
}
```

I have a .NET object that I know correctly represents the Message (the 'value' of item "349149733:-4:0:0" with name, text properties etc) but I can't seem to parse the array part?

I would like to have json.net auto-parse into an collection type object that I can simply interate over and get each message.

Comment: I can't understand the question

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json.NET will be able to serialize the `messages` value to an object of type `IDictionary<string, Message>`.

```
JObject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(text);
IDictionary<string, Message> messages =
    jsonObject["messages"].ToObject<IDictionary<string, Message>>();
```

You can then iterate over the dictionary entries (key-value pairs with the key and the `Message`), or over the values alone.

Comment: Thanks... although I had already just figured this out after trial and error.  I currently have something that works but might be slightly overkill:    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Messaging.Message>> MessagesById = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Messaging.Message>>>(output);

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
var xyz = JSON.parse('{"messages":{"349149733:-4:0:0":{ "name":"Fred","text":"Body for test message.",   "subject":"Test Message 1","referenceId":"349149733"}}}');
console.log(xyz.messages['349149733:-4:0:0']);
```